# Multiple languages quizzes. Should user's submitted answers be displayed in the new language if user switches language?

Tags: forms, language

If a user has submitted an answers in a quiz, then switches language, should that answer be displayed in the new language or should that question appear incomplete?

Comment: Are these open-ended questions (the user writes an answer) or closed-ended, such as multiple choice?

Comment: Hi there, yes they are open ended. Close ended like multiple choice/ response would display complete.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your value proposition.

There isn't a right way to do something. You need to understand your users, behaviors, pain and needs.

- Does your plataform have different kinds of user?
- How do they feel when they see a question in another idiom?
- Would they like to see a question in a native idiom?
- When users interact and change the language, should your system translate the answer to?

It's more about your business and your users!

Comment: I agreed, there is no such thing as bad design. It's all about the user's perspective, how effective your design on helping the user flow

Comment: Typically one would look at the costs associated with providing the feature, determining the ROI (Return On Investment), in conjunction with User expectations, product strategy, and the competitive landscape. You may find that User Testing alone exceeds you budget.

Comment: Thanks both. the quiz is produced in several languages, the platform detects the default language of the user's browser and displays the quiz accordingly, yet he can switch language. No, his/her answers are not translated. I thought that close ended question (mutliple choice/checkboxes) in other languages would display compelted as it would be in a survey. If you indicate your gender or nationality and then switch language your option is stil valid. With open ended question.. I think we should display the question as submitted, otherwise they will appear as incomplete in all other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You clarified that the user's answers would be open-ended (write-in), so I would recommend that you **do not change** them to another language if the user switches languages mid-quiz. As of late 2020, systems do not translate perfectly 100% of the time, which could cause a user's intent to be misinterpreted. Better to display answers in the original language that the user entered, allow the user to change their answers to the second language themselves, and let the system accept answers in both languages.

If it is not acceptable to allow the user to change their answers once entered, consider not allowing the user to switch languages in the middle of the quiz. Force them to start from the beginning of the quiz in the second language.

Comment: Thanks, yes on thinking again, it is the quiz that is multi-lingual not the answers. So open-ended answers written in english stay in english, but the question switches to the new language. If the user skips back, he/she should find what has left behind. Although I would allow the user to switch language mid quiz. I don't see anything firing back on this.